# Test multiple file conditions in one swoop (BASH)?

Tags: bash, testing, scripting, syntax

Often when writing for the bash shell, one needs to test if a file (or Directory) exists (or doesn't exist) and take appropriate action.  Most common amongst these test are...

`-e` - file exists, `-f` - file is a regular file (not a directory or device file), `-s` - file is not zero size, `-d` - file is a directory, `-r` - file has read permission, `-w` - file has write, or `-x` execute permission (for the user running the test)

This is easily confirmed as demonstrated on this **user-writable directory**....

```
#/bin/bash

if [ -f "/Library/Application Support" ]; then
echo 'YES SIR -f is fine'
else echo 'no -f for you'
fi

if [ -w "/Library/Application Support" ]; then
echo 'YES SIR -w is fine'
else echo 'no -w for you'
fi

if [ -d "/Library/Application Support" ]; then
echo 'YES SIR -d is fine'
else echo 'no -d for you'
fi
```

**➝ no -f for you  ✓

➝ YES SIR -w is fine ✓

➝ YES SIR -d is fine  ✓**

My question, although seemingly obvious, and unlikely to be impossible - is how to simply *combine* these tests, without having to perform them separately for each condition...  Unfortunately...

```
if [ -wd "/Library/Application Support" ]  
  ▶  -wd: unary operator expected

if [ -w | -d "/Library/Application Support" ]   
  ▶  [: missing `]'
  ▶  -d: command not found

if [ -w [ -d "/Library.... ]]   &  if [ -w && -d "/Library.... ] 
  ▶  [: missing `]'
```

**➝ no -wd for you ✖

➝ no -w | -d for you ✖

➝ no [ -w [ -d .. ]] for you ✖

➝ no -w && -d for you ✖**

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 43):

You can use logical operators to multiple conditions, e.g. `-a` for `AND`:

```
MYFILE=/tmp/data.bin
if [ -f "$MYFILE"  -a  -r "$MYFILE"  -a  -w "$MYFILE" ]; then
    #do stuff
fi
unset MYFILE
```

Comment: that requires writing the path twice.  is it really necessary?

Comment: That's why I used a variable to reduce duplication. You can make it even shorter if you like, just be careful not to clash with anything that already exists.

Comment: `-a` is not POSIX anymore, it appears, it's worth noting. Don't expect it to work in all shells. (I looked at `man 1posix test` at least in Debian Sid).

Answer (score 27):

Of course, you need to use AND somehow as Kerrek(+1) and Ben(+1) pointed it out. You can do in in few different ways. Here is an ala-microbenchmark results for few methods:

Most portable and readable way:

```
$ time for i in $(seq 100000); do [ 1 = 1 ] && [ 2 = 2 ] && [ 3 = 3 ]; done
real    0m2.583s
```

still portable, less readable, faster:

```
$ time for i in $(seq 100000); do [ 1 = 1 -a 2 = 2 -a 3 = 3 ]; done
real    0m1.681s
```

bashism, but readable and faster

```
$ time for i in $(seq 100000); do [[ 1 = 1 ]] && [[ 2 = 2 ]] && [[ 3 = 3 ]]; done
real    0m1.285s
```

bashism, but quite readable, and fastest.

```
$ time for i in $(seq 100000); do [[ 1 = 1 && 2 = 2 && 3 = 3 ]]; done
real    0m0.934s
```

Note, that in bash, "[" is a builtin, so bash is using internal command not a symlink to /usr/bin/test exacutable. The "[[" is a bash keyword. So the slowest possible way will be:

```
time for i in $(seq 100000); do /usr/bin/\[ 1 = 1 ] && /usr/bin/\[ 2 = 2 ] && /usr/bin/\[ 3 = 3 ]; done
real    14m8.678s
```

Comment: Nice eval. I was shocked that `[[` is actually faster than `[`. Any idea why?

Comment: @bitmask: Probably because it's a built-in Bash construct, rather than an OS command.

Comment: @l0b0: So is `[` here! As noted by Michael above.

Comment: @bitmask: Sorry, but that's wrong. Compare `which [` and `which [[`. `[` is a generic program which can be run in any shell, while `[[` is special Bash built-in syntax which is *not portable*.

Comment: @l0b0: Of course there is a proper `test`/`[` program sitting in `/usr/bin/` but that does not stop `bash` from using its own built-in implementation of `[`. First of all, it is noted in `man test` and `man bash` / `man builtins`. Second, if you look at the benchmark results, there is an obvious penalty if you explicitly use `/usr/bin/[` instead of `[` (~13.8 minutes versus ~2.5 seconds).

Comment: @bitmask: I think, that [[ is faster than [, because the "[[" is a keyword for evaluating expression, while [ is a internal builtin command. For command you need much bigger machinery. Something like simple expression in C versus calling function doing same calculation.

Comment: @l0b0 You should use `type` instead of `which` to check how shell sees a command and what will be executed. `type [`: _[ is a shell builtin_ and `type [[`: _[[ is a shell keyword_ Command `which` only locates a command and doesn't know anything about shell builtins.

Comment: @Pawel: That's really sweet. Didn't know about `type`, thanks!

Comment: @Gordon, any reference for "-a and -o are unary"? `man test` says otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, unary is the wrong word. They are undefined (by POSIX) for a test with more than four arguments, so are not portable. `-a` also has higher precedence than `-o`, which could be confusing behavior for any script that also uses `&&` or `||` anywhere else.
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest has a short bit on it.

Answer (score 9):

You want `-a` as in `-f foo -a -d foo` (actually that test would be false, but you get the idea).

You were close with `&` you just needed `&&` as in `[ -f foo ] && [ -d foo ]` although that runs multiple commands rather than one.

Here is [a manual page for test](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) which is the command that `[` is a link to.  Modern implementations of `test` have a lot more features (along with the shell-builtin version `[[` which is documented in your shell's manpage).

Comment: According to [these guys](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html)... "`-a` file exists -  This is identical in effect to -e. It has been "deprecated,"  and its use is discouraged."  Deprecated is then footnoted with this... Per the 1913 edition of Webster's Dictionary:
Deprecate
...

To pray against, as an evil;
to seek to avert by prayer;
to desire the removal of;
to seek deliverance from;
to express deep regret for;
to disapprove of strongly.

Comment: @Alex: That's something else, don't worry about it. Now `-a` means "and".

Answer (score 3):

```
check-file(){
    while [[ ${#} -gt 0 ]]; do
        case $1 in
           fxrsw) [[ -f "$2" && -x "$2" && -r "$2" && -s "$2" && -w "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
            fxrs) [[ -f "$2" && -x "$2" && -r "$2" && -s "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
             fxr) [[ -f "$2" && -x "$2" && -r "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
              fr) [[ -f "$2" && -r "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
              fx) [[ -f "$2" && -x "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
              fe) [[ -f "$2" && -e "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
              hf) [[ -h "$2" && -f "$2" ]] || return 1 ;;
               *) [[ -e "$1" ]] || return 1 ;;
        esac
        shift
    done
}

check-file fxr "/path/file" && echo "is valid"

check-file hf "/path/folder/symlink" || { echo "Fatal error cant validate symlink"; exit 1; }

check-file fe "file.txt" || touch "file.txt" && ln -s "${HOME}/file.txt" "/docs/file.txt" && check-file hf "/docs/file.txt" || exit 1

if check-file fxrsw "${HOME}"; then
    echo "Your home is your home from the looks of it."
else
    echo "You infected your own home."
fi
```

Comment: Using [[ -f "$file" -a -x "$file ]] is not recommended. One should use [[ -f "$file" ]] && [[ -d "$file" ]] or [[ -f "$file" && -x "$file ]] instead. Also there is a lot of redundancy here for example first testing for -e and then -x is redundant, because -x would return false if the file doesn't exist. Same thing for many other combinations. The example i posted is not meant to be taken literally, but rather a guide.

Answer (score 2):

Why not write a function to do it?

```
check_file () {
    local FLAGS=$1
    local PATH=$2
    if [ -z "$PATH" ] ; then
        if [ -z "$FLAGS" ] ; then
            echo "check_file: must specify at least a path" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        PATH=$FLAGS
        FLAGS=-e
    fi
    FLAGS=${FLAGS#-}
    while [ -n "$FLAGS" ] ; do
        local FLAG=`printf "%c" "$FLAGS"`
        if [ ! -$FLAG $PATH ] ; then false; return; fi
        FLAGS=${FLAGS#?}
    done
    true
}
```

Then just use it like:

```
for path in / /etc /etc/passwd /bin/bash
{
    if check_file -dx $path ; then
        echo "$path is a directory and executable"
    else
        echo "$path is not a directory or not executable"
    fi
}
```

And you should get:

```
/ is a directory and executable
/etc is a directory and executable
/etc/passwd is not a directory or not executable
/bin/bash is not a directory or not executable
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work (notice the double brackets):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -fwd "/Library/Application Support" ]]
then
    echo 'YES SIR -f -w -d are fine'
else
    echo 'no -f or -w or -d for you'
fi
```

Comment: This doesn't work on my shell :
Linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @Florian So apparently I gave an invalid answer. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413168/test-multiple-file-conditions-by-combining-flags-does-it-work.