# then not expected error on k shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I wrote a simple k shell program, but i seeing the following error
" 0403-057 Syntax error at line 11 : `then' is not expected."

The code is

```
 #!/usr/bin/ksh
    function check_rm 
   {
  number=$#    #assign number of parameters
if [[ $1 -gt 0 ]]; #if RC is success
    then 


        if[[ "$number" -gt 2 ]];  
        then         

        /usr/bin/mv  $4  $3
        echo " ERROR for $2 " 
    fi


    #user_name=`whoami`
    #mail_body="$3 checked in by $user_name" 
    #echo $mail_body 

else 


        if[[ "$number" -gt 2 ]];  
            then 

            /usr/bin/rm -rf $4
        fi      
        echo "GOOD for $2  "   
        echo "3f was successful"
fi
```

}

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 3):

As Wrikken noted in the comments, the problem is the missing space on that line between the `if` and the `[[`; ksh needs this to tell the two are separate. There's the same problem later in the script; you'll need to fix up both occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

You might remove the ";" after your if condition. A if condition has a very strict syntax, i corrected your code:

```
     #!/usr/bin/ksh

    function check_rm 
    {
        #assign number of parameters
        number=$#    
        #if RC is success
        if [[ $1 -gt 0 ]] 
        then 
            if [[ ${number} -gt 2 ]]
            then         
                /usr/bin/mv  $4  $3
                echo " ERROR for $2 " 
            fi


            #user_name=`whoami`
            #mail_body="$3 checked in by $user_name" 
            #echo $mail_body 

        else 
            if [[ ${number} -gt 2 ]]
            then 
                /usr/bin/rm -rf $4
            fi      
            echo "GOOD for $2  "   
            echo "3f was successful"
        fi                  

    }
```

Comment: -1: the semicolon after the if condition is fine; try it for yourself. Your changes make the code worse in other places, such as using `[ … ]` instead of `[[ … ]]`.

Comment: "should" is a mistake, i would wrote "might"... Btw "if [ ... ]" is prefered by "man test", so i cant get it how my suggestion get the code worst ... so constructive argument ... thank a lot !

Comment: `[` is an alias for `test`, which is normally a stand-alone executable in Unix systems, and which is why `man test` will recommend it. `[[ … ]]` is interpreted by the shell itself, which means it's faster (doesn't have to call an external executable) and has a less fragile syntax. Check out the man pages for the shells themselves (`man bash`, `man ksh`, `man zsh`, …)

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I looked by myself and i see you were right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916559/test-multiple-file-conditions-in-one-swoop-bash)