# Linux Column Sort Function

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I am trying to sort a file with 4 columns by the column that is input. My code below will only sort based on the first column no matter what the input of $field is.

```
if (( sort ))
then
        if [ $field==1 ]
        then
                sort -k1 $file -o $file
        elif [ $field==3 ]
        then
                sort -k3 $file -o $file
        elif [ $field==4 ]
        then
                sort -k4 $file -o $file
        else #for field 2-- this is default
                sort -k2 $file -o $file
        fi
fi
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the problem used in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) to illustrate how to turn a bad question into a good question.

Comment: (The duplicate is tagged `ksh`, but the answer applies here.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done more simply:

```
if [ $field -lt 1 -o $filed -gt 4 ]; then
    filed=2
fi
sort -k$field $file -o $file
```

**Update**. Previous version works if `field` contains number.
Here is new one using built in bash test `[[`:

```
if [[ ! $field =~ ^[0-9]+$ || $field < 1 || $field > 4 ]]; then
    filed=2
fi
sort -k$field $file -o $file
```

Here `$field =~ '^[0-9]+$'` is checking is variable contain number.

Comment: Don't use `-o`; use `[ "$field" -lt 1 ] || [ "$field" -gt 4 ]` instead.

Comment: @chepner why? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6917370/1677270), where `-o`/`-a` marked as less readable. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: They are only pseudo-standard (they are an optional extension to the POSIX standard); they are not quite deprecated, but the POSIX standard considers them obsolete and [recommends you not use them](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16). (They are essentially supported for historical reasons.)